# video play and stop in android from xml parser

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, audiovideoplayback

I have follows below xml feed:

```
<videourl>
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cHM0sm6aFtM?fs=0" width="500" height="298" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" ></iframe >
  </videourl>
```

Here how can i play video ???

i have wrote the below code:

```
  VideoView mVideo = new VideoView(this);
     mVideo.setLayoutParams(videoLayoutParams);
     mVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.bogotobogo.com/Video/sample.3gp"));
     MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
     mVideo.setMediaController(mc);
  mVideo.requestFocus();
     mVideo.start();
```

Here the video is play well..

But i have add these code

```
 mVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Appscontent.Sub_arraylistvideosub.get(j)));
```

after run the app means the app is force closed.

**EDIT:**

Yes i have used SAX parser here:

```
  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("videourl")) {
     isVideos = true;
        } 

      if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("iframe")) {
      if (isVideos)
       {
     String videosurl = attributes.getValue("src");
      sitesList.setVideos(videosurl);
      System.out.println("video value----->"+n+att_ID+"------>>"+videosurl);
      String Sub_arry=n+videosurl;
       Appscontent.Sub_arraylistvideo.add(Sub_arry);
       }}
```

Now i have to run the app means am getting the force clsoed error.how can i resolve these...please provide me solution for these ???

Which means am getting the app is force closed..why my app is force closed.please give me solution for these ???

Answer (score 0):

Using [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) you can take out the link from the XML.

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = saxBuilder.build("url to the xml feed");
Element root = document.getRootElement();
Element iframeElement = root.getChild("iframe");
String youtubeUrl = iframeElement.getAttributeValue("src");
```

Then you can use the youtubeUrl to show the video:  mVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(youtubeUrl));